# Getting a Paragraph that changes with dropdown using Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, underscore.js

I've gotten my dropdown to be populate with lessons, but then I am stuck trying to figure out how I can get the text beneath my dropdown to change based on what the user selects by using Backbone.js

I am populating a select by adding options containing my Lessons and having the title show. Now I am just stuck on where should I insert the  text so that it will change based on the selection.

Here is my HTML:

```
<script type="text/template" id="lesson-template">
<span class="lesson-title"><%= title %></span>
//How should I insert the text?
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="library-template">
<h1> Lesson Library </h1>
<select class="lessons"></select>
</script>
```

Here is my JSON file where I pull the information, I want to show the title now:
[{
    "title": "Intro",
    "text":"Do this now"
},
{
    "title": "Second",
    "text":"And then this"
}]

This is what is included in my javascript file:

```
window.Lesson = Backbone.Model.extend({});

window.Lessons = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Lesson,
    url: './lessons.json'
});

window.library = new Lessons();

window.LessonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'option',
    className: 'lesson',
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this,'render');
        this.model.bind('change',this.render);
        this.template = _.template($('#lesson-template').html());
    },

    render: function() {
        var renderedContent = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
        $(this.el).html(renderedContent);
        return this;
    }
});


window.LibraryLessonView = LessonView.extend({
});

window.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'section',
    className: 'library',

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.template = _.template($('#library-template').html());
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
    },

    render: function() {

        var $lessons,
        collection = this.collection;

        $(this.el).html(this.template({}));
        $lessons = this.$('.lessons');
        this.collection.each(function(lesson) {
            var view = new LibraryLessonView({
                model: lesson,
                collection: collection
            });
            $lessons.append(view.render().el);
        });
        return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First give an `id` to each lesson.

```
window.LessonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    render: function() {
        var renderedContent = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
        $(this.el).html(renderedContent);

        // Then put the id as the option's value
        $(this.el).val(this.model.get('id'));

        return this;
    }
    ...
});

window.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    // bind the select's onchange event to this.onSelect
    events: {
        'change select': 'onSelect'
    },
    ...

    ...
    onSelect: function(e) {
        // Grab the id of the select lesson
        var lessonId = $(e.target).val();

        // And get the lesson data back
        var lesson = _.indexBy(this.collection.toJSON(), 'id')[lessonId];

        // Then you could render you lesson view with something like this :
        $('#target-container').html(
            _.template($('#lesson-template').html(), lesson)
        );

    },
    ...

});
```

You could also go for a more elaborate views / collections construct but I'd suggest you get this working first.

Comment: Yes, this part was pretty simple, but I'm curious as to how I should add the text below the dropdown? Where should I include a <p> in the lesson-template? And to change that <p>, I would be accessing it from the OnSelect method correct?

Comment: Include a <p> right where you put your comment. Drop the view if one exists and create a new one passing it the selected model.

Comment: Could I put the <p> in another part of my body and then in the OnSelect and change that HTML element? Is this allowed?

Comment: Everything is allowed. "Sadly" with backbone most architectural choices are up to you. Is this a good choice ? I'm not sure it is. Marionette provides app-level messaging that may be useful here. In short, you could publish an event page-wide from LibraryView and catch it in another view (containing the <p>) that subscribes to this event. See Amy Palamountain's talk about Backbone and Marionette, and check Marionette Event Aggregator.